# property not found on object of type error but property is there

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I'm trying to access the property isPortClosed(BOOL) in SerialPortController and its giving me an error, I'm kinda new to objective-c. I feel like this should work as I've got a reference to the class with *port. Here is a link to the [project.](http://sharing.is.caring.s3.amazonaws.com/GroundStation)

Error messages:    ~/GroundStation/GroundStation/ViewController.m:16:22: Property 'isPortClosed' not found on object of type 'SerialPortController *'

```
        #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import "SceneView.h"
    #import "SerialPortController.h"

    @interface ViewController : NSViewController
    @property (strong) IBOutlet SerialPortController *port;
    @property (weak) IBOutlet SceneView *accelSceneView;



    @end
    #import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    while(!self.port.isPortClosed) {

    }
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

@end
```

SerialPortController.h class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <ORSSerial/ORSSerial.h>

@interface SerialPortController : NSObject <ORSSerialPortDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ORSSerialPort *serial;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ORSSerialPortManager *serialPortManager;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger xAngle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger yAngle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger zAngle;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *stringBuffer;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPortClosed;
@end
```

Comment: Please post the full output of error.

Comment: Show the .h file for the `SerialPortController` class.

Comment: @rmaddy added the class header in

Comment: This may be a naming convention issue. Try changing the property definition to: `@property (nonatomic, getter=isPortClosed) BOOL portClosed;`.

Comment: hm, maybe an automatic thing going on in the background... does it work if you rename the property to portClosed ? @rmaddy is pointing to exactly what I have thought, he just worded it much better.

Comment: @rmaddy same error, no change

Comment: added a download link to the project, I might be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the downloaded project I see that you have two `SerialPortController` class definitions (one at the root directory, and one in /GroundStation/), and the latter doesn't have any public properties. You should have only one `SerialPortController` class definition linked in your project (the one with the public properties).

Comment: if I could kiss you I would. I don't even know how I managed to pull this off.  My stupidity never seizes to amaze me.

Comment: No worries, it happens even to the bests developers :)